# Regex to check if string is just made up of special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have some strings for which i have to check whether it is made up of all special characters in regex i tried something but its not working the way i want any help ?

```
str = "@#%^"
regex = /[\?\<\>\'\,\?\[\]\}\{\=\-\)\(\*\&\^\%\$\#\`\~\{\}\@]/
str.match(regex)
```

Comment: what would be the way you want it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with

```
/\A\W*\z/
```

The `\W*` matches any non-word character from the beginning (`\A`) till the end (`\z`) of string.

See [demo](https://ideone.com/TJ2jyF):

```
class String
  def onlySpecialChars?
    !!self.match(/\A\W*\z/)
  end
end

puts "@#%^".onlySpecialChars?   # true
puts "w@#%^".onlySpecialChars?  # false
```

If you have your own set of special characters, just use instead of `\W`. Just also note you have overescaped your regex, `` [?<>',?\[\]}{=)(*&^%$#`~{}@-] `` will suffice.

Comment: There are a lot of questions related to matching special characters, but in fact, there is no unque definition of a special character. Thus, in general, you can either use pre-defined sets (your approach), or `\W`. In case you want to allow some non-word characters, you need to use a negated counterclass in a character class, e.g. `[^\w\s]` to allow whitespace. Or `[^\w\s\p{P}]` to allow both whitespace and punctuation.

Comment: in your answer can include dollar because its throwing error if my string has $ in it :/

Comment: Sorry, I guess it was a display error, just fixed it. You must be trying `!!self.match(/\A[?<>',?\[\]}{=)(*&^%$#\`~{}@-]*\z/)`, right? It is not easy to display `\``  :(

Comment: i did this  ```regex = %r{\A\W*\z}
  matched = realname.match(regex)
  if matched!= nil
   false
  else
   true
  end```

Comment: And what text does the `realname` hold?

Comment: Sorry its realname = "#$%" anything with special chars

Comment: It is [working for me](https://ideone.com/ByRj7P). Or did you just want to `return false` and `return true`?

Comment: I am really sorry but if some strings end with ```$``` i got that issue